# Simpliest method for sniffing network activity

Tags: c#, c, packet-sniffers

I have used packed inspection program such as WireShark and others and I have observed that most of them relay on the pcap driver.

Recently I stumbled over a source code written in C# witch intercepted traffic in a few lines of code. My questions are:

1. Is pcap driver or something similar included in .NET ?
2. Is possible to realize the same sniffing using traditional Windows API ?
3. If yes what are the drawbacks and why installing pcap is preferred ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`Is possible to realize the same sniffing using traditional Windows API ?`

Yes you can use the WFP call-out driver

`If yes what are the drawbacks and why installing pcap is preferred ?`

pcap installs the driver and corresponding user mode dll's , it is easy to use. 
Otherwise you have to write ur own filter driver and corresponding user mode code.